# Why do the particles in my fluid sim move to the left with no added velocity?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I was setting up a fluid sim and noticed that even with no added velocity or anything like that changed the particles fly to the left. Why is that and how can I fix it? The effectors don't seem to work either. All effectors have the same settings.

[.blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/f6ef4199a24140fca9f1294919ec973f)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I baked the fluid data it worked fine.